# Need to assign pointer to a function generated from a function template (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I have a function that takes following arguments as below -

```
int X::MainFun(Pfn, void*,int)
```

and Pfn is defined as

```
int (*Pfn) (int*, void*, int);
```

Now I have a function template as follows :

```
template <typename IntfType>
static int MasterOps(int * pRec, void* pSt, int pOffset ){
    IntfType* IfObj = (IntfType*) (((MasterOpArgs*)pSt)->vIfObj);
    if(IfObj->MasterOps(pRec, pSt, pOffset) == MIGINTF_SUCC) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Now I am calling function MainFun as -

```
MasterOpArgs margs;
Xobj->MainFun(MasterOps<MigT>, &margs,0 );
```

type `MigT` is a class defined earlier which implements a member `MasterOps` and `MainFun()` is actually a member function of some class.

Definition of template and call for `MainFun()` is happening in same file.

I assumed that call to `MainFun` would also cause instantiation of function template `MasterOps` with type `MigT`, but it seems I am wrong as I see following errors

```
error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'Pfn': note: None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
error C2059: syntax error: ','
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. The error talks about an overloaded function, but in your post there is only 1 overload

Comment: I do not find any other function MasterOps() to call it overloaded function. There is however a member function with same name and same signature in class MigT as explained

Comment: please show the code instead of describing it. Read about [mcve]

Comment: Excuse me please, I have found the source of overload and it seems to be strange issue - The compiler does not lets me keep same name for function template and member function. When I changed the name of the function template to "MasterOp", i.e omitted an 's' it started compiling fine and the problem comes as soon as I make the name same. Should I ask a separate question for this?

Comment: You claim you observe a compiler error. If you would like assistance with that, you need to show enough code to reproduce that error. If you suspect the error might be related to a class having two member functions with the same name, then your example should show two functions with the same name. This is what it means to prepare a [mcve]. Mind-reading abilities having yet to be perfected, it's difficult to help with code one cannot see.